# SQL Query: I need both rows if values exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an accounting situation where we're both paid (policy Transaction Type NBS) and negative (policy Transaction Type cancellation or XLN) on the same accounting situation. I need rows that only have both Tran Type of 'NBS' and 'XLN' for the same customer.

Example Data:

```
    Client     PolicyNo  Revenue   TranType
   -------------------------------------------
    John Doe   Pol1234   1000.00     NBS
    John Doe   Pol1234  -1000.00     XLN
    Jane Loe   Pol5675   9000.00     NBS
    Jane Loe   Pol5676   8000.00     NBS
    Bill Foe   Pol0985   1000.00     NBS
    Bill Foe   Pol0987  -1000.00     XLN
```

The query needs to only return the first two rows as both Client and PolicyNo match but also because each one is NBS and XLN. If both lines for the same customer are NBS or they are both XLN it needs to be excluded. If the PolicyNo does not match it needs to be excluded.

Right now, my query returns the full set. (I omitted some columns from my example above for simplicity.

```
SELECT 
Company_1.Name, 
isnull(Customer.FirmNameCust, 
isnull(Customer.FirstName + ' ', '') +  isnull(Customer.LastName, '')) AS Client,
BasicPolInfo.PolNo,                            
DirectBillEntryHeader.StmtDate, 
irectBillEntryHeader.Description, 
DirectBillEntryDetail.*
FROM DirectBillEntryHeader 
INNER JOIN 
DirectBillEntryDetail 
ON DirectBillEntryHeader.DBEHId = DirectBillEntryDetail.DBEHId 
INNER JOIN BasicPolInfo 
ON DirectBillEntryDetail.PolId = BasicPolInfo.PolId 
INNER JOIN Customer 
ON DirectBillEntryDetail.CustId = Customer.CustId 
AND BasicPolInfo.CustId = Customer.CustId 
INNER JOIN Company 
ON DirectBillEntryDetail.WritingCoCode = Company.CoCode 
INNER JOIN Employee 
ON Customer.Prod1Code = Employee.EmpCode 
INNER JOIN Company Company_1 
ON Company.ParentCoCode = Company_1.CoCode
       WHERE (DirectBillEntryDetail.TranType = 'NBS') 
       AND (DirectBillEntryHeader.StmtDate >= DateAdd(DD, - 30, GETDATE())) 
       OR (DirectBillEntryDetail.TranType = 'XLN')
       AND (DirectBillEntryHeader.StmtDate >= DateAdd(DD, - 30, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: You show nice simple sample data.  Then you show a query that has seven tables.  Can you simplify the question to focus on what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You could use  `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM dbo.TableName t1
WHERE t1.TranType IN('NBS','XLN')
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t2
    WHERE t1.Client = t2.Client
      AND t1.PolicyNo = t2.PolicyNo
      AND t1.TranType <> t2.TranType
      AND t2.TranType IN('NBS','XLN')   
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all client/policies that have both types by use of GROUP BY and HAVING. Then use this in your from clause so you get only those client/policies.

```
select ...
from
(
    select client, policyno 
    from mytable
    where trantype in ('NBS','XLN')
    group by client, policyno 
    having count(distinct trantype) = 2
) wanted
inner join sometable on sometable.client = wanted.client and sometable.policyno = wanted.policyno
...
```